# Is there any chance to avoid the high complexity of top-level Activity while using a Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, coding-style

I am currently rewriting my pure-Activity NFC application into a Navigation Drawer-based fragment structure. I must admit, that it is my first try with the fragments concept.

My current activity application consists of about 15 Activities, one SQLite ContentProvider and several HTTP and HTTPS AsyncTasks. There are also quite a lot of Dialogs (mostly standard) Everything is strictly encapsulated into separate files and easily maintainable.

In Fragment approach I use Navigation Drawer, top-level Activity and set of Fragments and DialogFragments.

I wonder is there any chance to split a top-level Activity, which grows to a enormous size because of taking responsibility of all invocations that are Activity-exclusive (such as taking care of all Alert and Progress Dialogs, NFC foreground dispatch etc.)?

I find it a bad practise to create such everything-responsible classes...

Comment: I use a base activity extending activity for everything pertaining to the drawer navigation and then a main activity extending base activity handles any dialog and alerts

Comment: @drees Thanks for the comment! Currently I use similar inheritance just to split the code, but I am not sure if it is the best I could do...